# Sending logs from .net core application running in App Service to log analytics

Tags: logging, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I tried looking for the simplest way of my .net core 2.0 application to send app logs to log analytics workspace.

This application is running under App Service in azure, and I tried enabling the "Diagnostic Settings" and archiving the logs to log analytics.

However, I am not seeing my app custom logs messages in: AppServiceHTTPLogs .

I have used the following guide:
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/11/01/App-Service-Integration-with-Azure-Monitor.html

My application is using ILoggerFactory:

```
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
        loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information);
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

Any idea of how to ship logs to there?

Answer (score 1):

I test and it works well in my site. You could refer to the following code:
In `startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    other codes...

    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
    loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Information);
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    other codes...
}
```

In HomeController:

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;

public HomeController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
     _logger.LogInformation("this is a information from ILogger...");
     return View();
}
```

Configure azure webapp Diagnostics settings as the [article](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2019/11/01/App-Service-Integration-with-Azure-Monitor.html) and then you will get the `appservicehttplogs`. Wait a few minutes, and it will be added to storage automatically.

[image]

Comment: What's AppServiceAppLogs & AppServiceConsoleLogs stands for?
How can I write custom logs from application to one of these logs ?

Comment: As the article, `AppServiceConsoleLogs`: Any logs or output written to the console. And `AppServiceAppLogs`: Any logs or exceptions written to the stack’s logging utility. Supports multi-line logs and exceptions.

Comment: So why these tables are empty ?

Comment: Like appservicehttplogs is log for webserver. And the code you provided it log for application..